# C allocating dynamic memory in a function - same results

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, dynamic

I tryed to create a multi-dimensional array and I wrote a function but when I check my matrices,  I've realized my pointers's values are the same but their addresses are diffrent. Why :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **matrix(int a,int b){
    int i;
    int **x;
    x = (int**)malloc(a * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        x[i] = (int*)malloc(b * sizeof(int));
    }
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int **m1, **m2;
    m1=matrix(3,3);
    m2=matrix(3,3);
    printf("Values: %d %d\n",m1[1][1],m2[1][1]);
    printf("Addresses: %d %d",&m1[1][1],&m2[1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Your values are uninitialized, so they can be anything. The addresses should be different, why did you expect the same?

Comment: after the allocation of m1 it gets an address. Then when m2 is allocated, it is allocated in a different address as m1 still exist and has not been de-allocated yet(dynamically allocated).

Comment: cause of I got the same results. I use code block and my screen output is 
Values: 3870600 3870600
Addresses: 3870684 3770780

Comment: sorry for my english .s

Comment: As already said, the first two values can be anything and the second two values are addresses which ought to be different !

Comment: so there is no reason to be same values, they can be anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Memory-leak-looming!*
First off, you have a possible memory-leaking program here. You are allocating memory for 2 *matrices*, but at no point to you `free` the allocated memory. You should. All memory allocated on the heap is your responsibility, it is your job to see to it that that memory is `free`'ed once you're done with it. Possibly implement a function like:

```
void free_matrix(int **matrix, int len)
{
    if (matrix == NULL) return;//don't try and free NULL pointers
    while(len--) free(matrix[len]);
    free(matrix);
}
```

to be called in your main function after you've printed out what needed printing out:

```
free_matrix(m1, 3);
m1 = NULL;//setting unused pointers to NULL is a good habit
free_matrix(m1,3);//won't cause problems
free_matrix(m2, 3);
free_matrix(m2, 1);//ERROR!
```

You also fail to check if and see if the `malloc` call actually was successful. If there isn't enough memory available, `malloc` returns null, and you should handle this. At the very least do:

```
some_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*some_ptr));
if (some_ptr == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);//macro expands to 1
```

Anyway, I've written [this codepad](http://codepad.org/Sd3xijgB) that tries to free and reassign the same matrix over and over, until the values in memory are different. As it turns out, on codepad at least, they're alwasy the same.
I'm currently browsing linux kernel code, and the web, to see if there is a reason for this. Perhaps Linux wipes the heap memory when the kernel is idling, or perhaps it's a codepad thing... either way, stay tuned for updates :)

Basically, `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory it allocates. What the OS does with free'd memory is up to the OS. I've tried the code below on my 64bit linux system, which compiled fine using

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall src.c -o temp
```

And it shows that the matrices *do* contain different values, but were, in my case mostly `0`. Anyway, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void **matrix(int a,int b)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int **x;
    x = malloc(a * sizeof(*x));
    if (x == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        x[i] = malloc(b * sizeof(*(x[i])));
        if (x[i] == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return (void **)x;
}

void free_matrix(void ***m, int l)
{
    if (*m == NULL) return;
    while(l--) free((*m)[l]);
    free(*m);
*m = NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int **m1, **m2, c=0;
    m1 = (unsigned int **) matrix(3,3);
    m2 = (unsigned int **) matrix(3,3);
    printf("%lu <> %lu\n", sizeof(m1[1][1]), sizeof(m1));//4 <> 4 -> 32 bit, 4 <> 8 -> 64
    while(*(m1[1]+1) == *(m2[1]+1) && c < 101)
    {
        ++c;
        free_matrix((void ***) &m1,3);
        m1 = (unsigned int **) matrix(3,3);
    }
    if (c == 101)
    {
        for(c=0;c<3;++c) printf("%u %u %u\n%u %u %u\n\n",*(m1[c]), *(m1[c]+1), *(m1[c]+2),*(m2[c]), *(m2[c]+1), *(m2[c]+2));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Different vals after %d tries\n", c);
    }
    printf("Values: %u %u %c\n",m1[1][1],m2[1][1], (unsigned char) m1[1][1]);
    printf("Addresses: %p %p\n",(void *) (m1[1]+1), (void *) (m2[1]+1));
    free_matrix((void ***)&m1, 3);
    free_matrix((void ***)&m2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

And an example of the output I got is here:

```
4  8
12546112 0 0
0 0 0

12546144 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0

Values: 0 0
Addresses: 0xbf7054 0xbf70d4
```

### Anyway, I hope this, and the rest of my answer clears a thing or two up for you.

To get the actual *addresses* you'll have to write:

```
printf("Addresses: %p, %p\n", (void *) &m1[1][1], (void *)&m1);
```

As opposed to:

```
printf("Addresses: %d %d",&m1[1][1],&m2[1][1]);
```

Because `m1[1][1]` *isn't* a pointer! `m1` is a pointer to a pointer to an int, so `m[1]` is a pointer to an int, and `m1[1][1]` *is an int*, not a pointer.

Oh, and casting the return value of `malloc` is not done. It hides possible errors, and `malloc` will return a compatible pointer type or `NULL` anyway.

But why are their addresses not the same? well simple: you're allocating 2 separate blocks of heap memory. You're not allocating the same memory twice (that would be impossible).
You're attempting to print out the address of those values that are stored in 2 separate locations in the heap.

***It's like building 2 houses that are exactly the same in every way, only you build them in a different city. Their addresses will be unique.***

The fact that the *values* are the same is a coincidence. `malloc` *does not change the contents of the memory*, so if the blocks of memory happened to be set to `0` since last they were used, then you'll happen to get zero initialized memory, but you can't be sure this will always be the case... The question you should be asking is not *why*, but *why not* or *what are the odds*

Comment: actually I want to asked why are values the same but i guess asked wrong question cause of I already know the addresses must be different

Comment: @BerkSahin: coincidence, Added that to my answer

Comment: @BerkSahin: I've done some more digging, and looked at your code. Check the codepad I linked to in my answer, which fixes a couple of issues with your code, and read the rest of my edit, because there might be a future update comming

Answer (score 1):

In case of m1[1][1], you are printing values in the array. They are not pointer values. Since you have not initialized them to any value, they can be anything. In your case, they are turning up to be same
&m1[1][1] is a pointer though. Since you are allocating memory twice, they have different values. (Different addresses for array)

Comment: You might consider editing your answer as your answer is not exactly saying what user is asking !